# Set the cursor of a readonly RichtTextBox

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, richtextbox

The following code avoids the Richtextbox of being focused. So the user can not edit the text or select it. To avoid the Cursor of changing to *IBeam* I also also catch the *SETCURSOR message*. But the Problem is, the richtextbox also contains links and I want the cursor to change to *Hand*, if I move the mouse over a link. So I have to distinguish between *IBeam* and *Hand*. For this I could not find a solution, altough I think this can not be so difficult.

```
Const WM_SETFOCUS = &H0007
Const WM_KILLFOCUS = &H0008
Const WM_SETCURSOR = &H0020
Const WM_NULL = &H0000

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef _M As Message)

    Select Case _M.Msg

        Case WM_SETFOCUS, WM_KILLFOCUS
            _M.Msg = WM_NULL

        Case WM_SETCURSOR
             'Here I need your help: How can I check the cursor?
             'If Cursor is IBeam Then
             '   _M.Msg = WM_NULL
             'End If

    End Select

    MyBase.WndProc(_M)

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll probably just want to set the `Cursor` property of the rich text box based on the contents.

Comment: it contains both, normal text and links. But if i move the mouse over a link, the cursor should be a *Hand* and otherwise it should be an *Arrow*. I just don't want the IBeam-Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This is for C# but you should be able to convert it:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectionLength > 0)
    { 
        int position = GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
        if (position > SelectionStart && position < SelectionStart+SelectionLength)
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        else
            this.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
    }

    base.OnMouseMove(e);
}
```

Comment: maybe my question was unclear:
I want a RTB, which can not be edited and textselection also should not be possible. for this reason I used the code in the question post and not the readonly property. I just catched the *WM_SETFOCUS-msg* and replaced it with *WM_NULL*, so that nothing is happening.

So the Control only should Display text. But the text also contains links. In case I move the Cursor over an link it has to Change from *arrow* to *Hand*. This happens automatically, but what I dont want, is that the Cursor changes to Ibeam, so I have check to which Cursor the RTB wants to Change.